# C# - Merge two objects of the same class and update all references?

Tags: c#, .net, merge

I have some Foo objects which are contained in Bar objects:

```
class Foo
{
    int uniqueId; // every Foo has a different ID.
    List<int> data;
}

class Bar
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
}
```

Sometimes I want to merge the Foo objects that belong to different Bars as follows:

```
public void MergeWith(Bar otherBar)
{
    this.foo.uniqueId = otherbar.foo.uniqueId;
    this.foo.data.AddRange(otherbar.foo.data);     

    otherBar.foo = this.foo;
    // Now both Bar objects refer to the same Foo, which contains all the data.
}
Bar bar1;
Bar bar2;
bar1.MergeWith(bar2);
```

This is fine. The problem is that these Bar objects have handed out a references to their `Foo` objects to `Baz` objects. `Baz` has a `List<Foo>` it's collected from multiple sources.

How can I get the `Baz` objects to know when their `Foo`s are outdated? Should the `Foo` objects have a reference to their "newer" `Foo`, linked list style? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Can you show how the `Baz` objects get the `Foo` references from `Bar`? Who is responsible for setting `Baz.Foos`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only think of two ways that early in the morning:

- Do not hand out a reference always
  use a property to return the current
  reference
- Implement a OnFooChange
  event and post the change to all
  parties interested from within the Bar class/ instance

hth

Mario